# Is it possible to CREATE CERTIFICATE using certificate from the Windows Certification Store?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, encryption, certificate

*Additional Information*

With `SQL Server 2016 SP1` we have the availability to use `Always Encrypted` functionality with the `Standard Edition` of the server. One is able to create a certificate in the `Windows Certification Store` and mapped this certificate to `COLUMN MASTER KEY` - then, use the `CMK` to protect `COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY` used for encrypting data in particular column.

Using `Windows Certification Store` is handy:

- because other `Extensible Key Management` providers are for the `Enterprise Edition` (like Hardware Security Modules - HSM)
- the access to the certificates is manage in central prlace
- we skip to levels of the encryption hierarchy (using Service Master Key and Database Master Key)

---

*Case scenario*

The `Always Encrypted` functionality is used to encrypted all data in a particular column. I need to encrypted only some of the data, so I need to use a `symmetric key` or `asymmetric key`. I want to protect them with a certificate which is stored in the `Windows Certification Store` in order to control the access to the keys from there. Is this possible to create such certificate?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want the key to be opened?  Is it using a certificate on the client computer?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft We have option to create a certificate using a file. I want instead of using a file as a source to use the windows certification store.

Comment: Not with SQL Server directly, but you can code your application to use the certificate in the certificate store to do the encryption/decryption without SQL Server being involved. `Always Encrypted` is part of the driver which does the encryption and decryption, not the database engine itself.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether or not you want server-side decryption.  But in any case for this scenario I would almost rather use two columns.  One encrypted and one not, and work across them in a view or in client code.

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft That's sounds good. Can you show me how I can use the `Always Encrypted` functions to encrypt values or give me a link to example/documentation?